# How to use variable in LIMIT statement in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, limit, offset, median

I am trying to return the median by using order by and returning the mid element. I am using limit to offest the first half and then return 1 row which will give median.

```
   SELECT
     COUNT(*) into @cnt FROM STATION;
    SELECT ROUND(LAT_N,4) 
    FROM STATION
    ORDER BY LAT_N
    LIMIT 1 OFFSET ((@cnt-1)/2)
```

I am getting error:-

ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 6: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '((@cnt-1)/2)' at line 4

Total no of rows = 499
so if I use

```
SELECT
 COUNT(*) into @cnt FROM STATION;
SELECT ROUND(LAT_N,4) 
FROM STATION
ORDER BY LAT_N
LIMIT 1 OFFSET 250
```

I don't get any error. SO why is error on first one?

Comment: Phew, would still love a proper solution to this one

Answer (score -1):

> SO why is error on first one?

Well, you will get an error if you make it a fair comparison by writing..

```
... OFFSET ((501-1)/2)
```

MySQL after 5.5 can parameterize LIMIT and OFFSET if you pass integer variables for them

Make it `OFFSET @cnt` and get your front end to do the calc for @cnt

Answer (score -1):

I suggest to modify your query like this:

```
SELECT
 COUNT(*) into @cnt FROM STATION;
SELECT ROUND(LAT_N,4) 
FROM STATION
ORDER BY LAT_N
LIMIT 1 OFFSET (@cnt - 1) / 2 ROWS FETCH NEXT 2 - @cnt % 2 ROWS ONLY )
```